# Modelsim wave color vsim

Tags: tcl, verilog, simulation, modelsim

I'm writing a **modelsim   .do** file to run my simulation . For faster debugging I need to use different colors for signal waves.

**I need to know which command i should use in my custom .do file to get this color change.**

below is a small part of my .do file

**TIA**

**Aditya**

```
restart -force -nowave

vsim -t 1ns
config wave -signalnamewidth 1
radix -hex

add wave -divider -height 30 "NoC READ / MASTER WRITE"
add wave sim:/NoC_new_again/rst
add wave sim:/NoC_new_again/clk
add wave sim:/NoC_new_again/CMD_READ
add wave sim:/NoC_new_again/ALE_READ
add wave sim:/NoC_new_again/READ_THIS

add wave -divider -height 30 "NoC WRITE / MASTER READ"
add wave sim:/NoC_new_again/CMD_READ
add wave sim:/NoC_new_again/ALE_READ

add wave -divider -height 30 " REGISTERS"
add wave sim:/NoC_new_again/READ_CODE
add wave sim:/NoC_new_again/READ_RESP_CODE
add wave sim:/NoC_new_again/WRITE_CODE
add wave sim:/NoC_new_again/WRITE_RESP_CODE
add wave sim:/NoC_new_again/MESSAGE_CODE
add wave sim:/NoC_new_again/SOURCE_ID
add wave sim:/NoC_new_again/RETURN_ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ModelSim `add wave` have `-color` option in the syntax like:

```
add wave ... [-color <standard_color_name>] ...
```

for example:

```
add wave -color white sim:/tb/clk
```

You can find full description in "ModelSim Command Reference Manual", which is usually available as PDF in the installation under "\modelsim_\docs\pdfdocs\modelsim_ref.pdf", or you can find some versions at [search for ModelSim Command Reference Manual](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ModelSim+Command+Reference+Manual+filetype%3Apdf&t=hq&ia=web), and hints are available in ModelSim using:

```
help add wave
```